# Как обрезать изображение в определенном порядке?

Tags: php

Такой код обрезает только: 1, 2, 3 часть. При добавлении еще 1 цикла for обрезка идет с другого края.

```
$file = "testing3.png";
$size = getimagesize($file);
$im = imagecreatefrompng($file);
$newIm = imagecreatetruecolor(64, 64);
$i = 1;
for($y = $size[1] - 64; $y >= 0; $y = $y - 64){
    imagecopy($newIm, $im, 0, 0, 0, $y, 64, 64);
    imagepng($newIm, "cut/" . $i++ . '.png');
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: режьте в нормальном порядке, потом пересортируете

Answer (score 0):

Вроде получилось, но создает не 15 кусков, а 18.

```
$i = 1;
for($xc = 0; $xc <= $size[0]; $xc = $xc + 64){
    for($y = $size[1] - 64; $y >= 0; $y = $y - 64){
        imagecopy($newIm, $im, 0, 0, $xc, $y, 64, 64);
        imagepng($newIm, "cut/" . $i++ . '.png');
    }
}
```